# Locate ChildHtml?

Tags: magento-1.9

In the header.phtml file of my magento site there is this code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerCart') ?>
```

I need to change some html within headerCart but how can I locate the ChildHtml?
New to Magento and very confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search for some block in the layouts ( `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/` ) with the `name = "headerCart"` or `as = "headerCart"`. In any other case, the child can be set in some other places: another blocks, controller or in admin.